# jquery on click function not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML component(remove-coordinate-component) - button(X)  and when I click that button want to alert a message but that is not working.

Currently I have a bounded that to a click function.

http://jsfiddle.net/awrf9c5s/5/

HTML:-

```
   <div class="row row-bordered">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="button" class="btn" id="add-aisle">Add</button>
              <div id="coordinate-container">

              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
          </div>
      </div>
```

js:

```
// scripts.js
var globals = {}
aisle_coordinate_component = '<div class="input-group"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Y"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X1"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Y1"> \
                              <button type="button" class="close remove-coordinate-component" aria-label="Close" > \
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> \
                              </button> \
                              </div>'


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add-aisle').click(function(){
        console.log(aisle_coordinate_component)
        $('#coordinate-container').append(aisle_coordinate_component);
    })

    $('.remove-coordinate-component').click(function(){
        alert('aisle coordinate component clicked')
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation and change the following

```
  $('.remove-coordinate-component').click(function(){
```

to

```
$("#coordinate-container").on('click','.remove-coordinate-component',function() {
```

here is the[**`demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/awrf9c5s/26/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the "remove" button doesn't exist yet when you try to attach the event handler to it. Therefore `$('.remove-coordinate-component')` doesn't select any elements, and so the handler is not attached to anything.

Use

```
$('#coordinate-container').on("click", '.remove-coordinate-component', function() {
```

to bind the event to an element which always exists, and then delegate it so that it actually fires only when the "remove" button within it is clicked. This allows the flexibility to search for elements within the container, so it will work even when the element in question is added later.

Demonstration:

```js
// scripts.js
var globals = {}
aisle_coordinate_component = '<div class="input-group"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Y"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X1"> \
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="Y1"> \
                              <button type="button" class="close remove-coordinate-component" aria-label="Close" > \
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> \
                              </button> \
                              </div>'


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#add-aisle').click(function() {
    console.log(aisle_coordinate_component);
    $('#coordinate-container').append(aisle_coordinate_component);
  });

  $('#coordinate-container').on("click", '.remove-coordinate-component', function() {
    alert('aisle coordinate component clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row-bordered">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="add-aisle">Add</button>
    <div id="coordinate-container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on/ under the section "direct and delegated events" for more detail.

P.S. This is effectively a duplicate of dozens of similar previous questions on the same topic, although they're not always easy to find because people describe the issue in multiple different ways

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$(document).on('click','.remove-coordinate-component',function(){       
    alert('aisle coordinate component clicked')
})
```

Comment: it's much more efficient to delegate down from the nearest permanent parent of the target element, then jQuery doesn't have to search the entire DOM to find a match. It's rare that it's necessary to delegate from `document` itself. Also, your answer would be much better with an explanation and/or working demo, as the other answers have got. Just dumping some code without saying why it helps does not really improve the understanding of anyone reading it.